# WSUS too big size for only one product in one language

Tags: windows, active-directory, wsus, windows-update

I'm downloading updates for only Windows 7 in English language.

Currently size of folder is 99Gb of 100 available.

I have tried to delete unused updates, pc non contating server etc (using wsus clean up wizard, all options checked).

Is it possible that there are that many updates for win 7 system?

Can I do anything to free up some space.

Thanks

Comment: Add more disk space? 100GB in 2016 is quite small.

Answer (score 1):

Review your classifications in the WSUS options.  If you included Drivers, you'll definitely get lots.  Also check whether you've selected to include express files - they're big.

You can view how many updates you have in total in the UI.
If you look in the WSUSContent folder, you can see how much of the disk space is allocated to update content actually downloaded.

Additionally you can have clients receive approvals and scan information from WSUS, and have them download the updates directly from Windows Update.  It's in the Console options under "Update Files and Languages," specifically the "Do not store updates locally; computers install from Microsoft Update."   While there, also double check you're only using languages you need.

I assume you're using a local built in DB, rather than a standalone SQL also in that 100GB.